# POSTing to Zendesk Api receiving 403

Tags: zendesk-api

I'm trying to load a ticket into a currently logged in users browser as shown here, https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/voice-api/talk_partner_edition#open-ticket-in-agents-browser.

I've tried POSTing using both Postman & cURL but receive 403 Forbidden. I've tried authenticating with my known Zendesk user&password combo.

> curl
>   https://XXXXXX.zendesk.com/api/v2/channels/voice/agents/XXXX/tickets/XXXXX/display.json
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -u XXXX@XXXXXXXX.co.uk:XXXXXXXXXXX -X POST

Does anyone know what I could need to do extra?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Talk Partner Edition enabled on your account?  This error is common if you don't have a subscription for that specific product.  Please contact the support team if you are not sure.